# Angular2 Http Providers on ES5 (not TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on an app and I'm playing around with Angular2 for fun. I'm using ES5 JavaScript, and my question right now is how do I access the Http service? All of the documentation available is TypeScript (which is not helpful) or it's for an alpha version of Angular2, and the system has changed since.

I'm using Angular2 version 2.0.0-beta.13. I am receiving the following error: `TypeError: ng.http.get is not a function in [null]`. I've tried using `ng.http.Http.get` to no avail. I have `angular2-all.umd.js` included in the head, as well as the other js requirements defined by angular.io (RxJS, es6 shims, polyfills, etc).

Here are the code snippets I have, for reference. All files are concatenated together for ease of reading.

```js
;(function (app, ng) {
    app.CommandService = (function () {
        var CommandService = function () {
            this.url = 'api/commands';
        };

        CommandService.prototype.all = function () {
            return ng.http.get(this.url)
                .map(function (response) {
                    return response.json().data;
                })
                .catch();
        };

        return CommandService;
    })();
})(window.app || (window.app = {}), window.ng);

;(function (app, ng) {
    app.CommandComponent = (function () {
        function CommandComponent(commandService) {
            this.commandService = commandService;
            this.commands       = [];
        }

        CommandComponent.parameters  = [
            app.CommandService
        ];
        CommandComponent.annotations = [
            new ng.core.Component({
                selector:    '#command-listing',
                templateUrl: 'api/templates/commands/listing',
                providers: [
                    app.CommandService,
                    ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS
                ]
            })
        ];

        CommandComponent.prototype.all      = function () {
            var self = this;

            this.commandService.all().subscribe(
                function (commands) {
                    self.commands = commands;
                }, function (error) {
                    self.error = error;
                }
            );
        };
        CommandComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = function () {
            this.all();
        };

        return CommandComponent;
    })();
})(window.app || (window.app = {}), window.ng);

;(function (app, ng) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.CommandComponent);
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}), window.ng);
```

From a timing perspective, TypeScript does not seem to be a viable option. I tried to set up the environment as needed, and after a full day of debugging TS issues, I now have SystemJS issues, so I'm hoping the plain JS option can suffice for now until I have time to figure out all of the intricacies.

Let me know if more information is needed; I'm happy to give it.

Comment: As a side note, I'd highly advise figuring out your SystemJS & TypeScript issues as it will make life with Angular2 MUCH easier. :)

Comment: I plan on it, for sure. I like the structure of TypeScript, but so far getting it working has been extremely off-putting.

Comment: Where do you get that way of declaring components from? I haven't seem it.

Comment: I think I took a lot of stuff from here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ts-to-js.html I may have modified things a few times, as I was getting frustrated trying to understand `ng.core.Component`, so I'm sure there are better ways to do things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `CommandService`:

```
;(function (app, ng) {
    app.CommandService = (function () {
        var CommandService = function (http) {           // this line changed
            this.url = 'api/commands';
            this.http = http;                            // this line added
        };

        CommandService.parameters  = [                   // this line added
            ng.http.Http // this will be passed as arg in the constructor
        ];                                               // this line added

        CommandService.prototype.all = function () {
            return this.http.get(this.url)               // this line changed
                .map(function (response) {
                    return response.json().data;
                })
                .catch();
        };

        return CommandService;
    })();
})(window.app || (window.app = {}), window.ng);
```

See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4FG1Lrt7Yhnzo20azV8Z?p=preview

Just as an additional info, you could remove from the `CommandComponent` (line 41 of `app/main.js`) and add the `ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS` at the `bootstrap()` like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.CommandComponent, [ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
});
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks! Regarding the last thing, I only added `ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS` in an attempt to figure out what I was missing. Is it necessary to have, or could I just get rid of it entirely?

Comment: It is necessary Mostly because the `Http` doesn't open connections itself. It actually uses a `ConnectionBackend` to create them. But `ConnectionBackend` is an `interface`, so `Http` needs you to provide a `ConnectionBackend` implementation for it to use. When you include [`HTTP_PROVIDERS`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/HTTP_PROVIDERS-let.html), you are providing `XHRBackend` (which uses `BrowserXHR`) as the `ConnectionBackend` implementation for your `Http` (an example of other implementation would be `MockBackend` normally used during tests).

Comment: Gotcha. And so the idea there is that by sending it in on `bootstrap()`, I never have to declare it again, regardless of wherever I want to use `Http`, yes?

Comment: Is there official documentation on this? I can't imagine a major framework like Angular 2 has no docs on using javascript ???

Comment: @Kokodoko Yes, there is. Usually, you can change the language of the guide in the combo located at the bottom left corner: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html that changes the code used. Not all pages are available in all languages, though.

Comment: Exactly, the HTTP documentation is not available for javascript, only for dart and typescript.... https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html I wonder if that means it's not possible?